# How to override a major mode's key bindings with a minor auto-complete mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

`TAB`, which is pretty convenient way to complete AC suggestions, but in many modes (`org`, `mediawiki-mode`) it has been already reserved for another operations. How to teach Emacs use `TAB` for `ac-complete` when there are suggestion (line or menu) and for the default major-mode binding otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was the bindings themselves. AC manual provides the following line:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map "\t" 'ac-complete)
```

But if wants to use `TAB` in a completing map, there is another binding to redefine:

```
(define-key ac-completing-map (kbd "<tab>") 'ac-complete)
```

With this line, at first `TAB` completes the word and then, the second hit of the `TAB`, do the major mode operation.